# Android Studio Build Variant window Grayed out w/ "Loading...."

Tags: android-studio

I'm trying to open my build Variant window, but its says: "Loading..." and there is a endless spinner in the top right corner.  Please see picture:

[image]

What could be the issue here?

Answer (score 0):

Problem was a deprecated plugin I had installed:  android-studio-unit-test-plugin